# Matplotlib imsave image with log norm

Tags: python, matplotlib, logarithm, colormap

How **could I save the image using the following colormap** option using Matplotlib?

The current syntax doesn't allow me to do it?

```
plt.imsave('C:/Users/Desktop/Img/image'+'_'+ str(i)+'.png', data)
```

I would like to add this to above:

```
norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm()
cmap=my_cmap
```

Ideally I would like:

```
plt.imsave('C:/Users/Desktop/Img/image'+'_'+ str(i)+'.png', data, norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(), cmap=my_cmap)
```

But this not possible.

Documentation of [`matplotlib.image.imsave(fname, arr, vmin=None, vmax=None, cmap=None, format=None, origin=None, dpi=100)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/image_api.html#matplotlib.image.imsave)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: TypeError: imsave() got an unexpected keyword argument 'norm'. I would like to add the norm, as it it possible to use it in imshow() but not in imsave()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially using a LogNorm is the same as taking the logarithm of the data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = plt.imread("house.png").mean(axis=2)
logdata = np.log(data)
plt.imsave("logimage.png", logdata, cmap="viridis")
```

If some of the values are zero, it may not be obvious how a log plot should look like. You may replace zeros by nan values beforehands (this is what LogNorm would do)

```
data[data == 0.] = np.nan
logdata = np.log(data)
```

or you may add a small amount to the data, such they are not zero any more

```
logdata = np.log(data+0.02)
```

Comment: Thanks but I exactly did your code and I am encountering this "error:RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log"   Would there be a workaround this?

Comment: This is not an error, but a warning, which you can ignore. The question is, how should values of zero be handled in a log plot? I updated the answer with two options.